# Progress bar for Angular Lazy Loading Components

Tags: javascript, angular, download, progress-bar, lazy-loading

I am developing an angular app. I am using lazy loading technique successfully to load components.
I want to place a loading bar that show progress of loading components in real.

**How can I get get size of component and loaded size to get percentage loaded.**

```
    import('myComponent.component').then(m => {
                  this.loadComponent( this.componentID, m.myComponent );
                })

    loadComponent( componentID:number, component:any ) {


    if( this.componentFactory[componentID] == undefined ) {

      this.componentFactory[componentID] = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory( component );
      this.componentRef[componentID] = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent( this.componentFactory[componentID] );

    }
    else {
      this.viewContainerRef.insert( this.componentRef[componentID]._viewRef );
    }

  }
```

Comment: Well, loading time depends on amount of data or requests, calculations. Component itself loads in no time. The actions component does might take time. So only your component instance is aware of that and only it can notify on loading state. It could f.e.x `emit()` loading state events

Comment: @JuliusDzidzevičius: Even if there are no API requests, lazy loading might be a heavy payload. For example if first loading an area with charts or grids.